# Angular 2 Full Reload on router.navigate

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, routes

I'm having an issue with doing a redirect following a form submission for logging in on Angular 2. The application performs a full reload on the redirect to dashboard. I have checked several posts on stack overflow & other blogs, with no luck. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711695/angular-2-app-reloading-on-route-change) is the closest one; However, there is no answer on the thread. See my code below.

After I press the login, the page loads, and then reloads again. The URL is also changing to put the query string in the URL, which I suspect is causing the issue. How can I fix this issue? I suspect is has something to do with the way my form is set up.

auth.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from '../shared/user';
declare var Materialize:any;

import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'logon',
  templateUrl: 'auth.component.html',
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser = new User(null, '', '', '', '', 'vistor');
  submitted = false;
  authForm: NgForm;
  @ViewChild('authForm') currentForm: NgForm;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public authService: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.authService.login(this.currentUser).then(response => {
      if (response) {
        this.goToDashboard();
      } else {
        var toastContent = '<span><b>Invalid email or password!</b></span>';
        Materialize.toast(toastContent, 5000, 'red');
      }
    });
  }

  goToDashboard() {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  }
}
```

auth.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">Logon</span>
      <form materialize #authForm="ngForm" class="col s12">

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input required class="validate" id="email" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="currentUser.email" #email="ngModel" validate="email">
          <label for="email" data-error="Invalid Email">Email</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input required class="validate" id="password" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="currentUser.password" #password="ngModel" validate="password">
          <label for="password" data-error="Invalid Password">Password</label>
        </div>

        <div class="card-action">
          <button [disabled]="!authForm.form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn orange darken-1 waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Log In
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular 2 Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'spelling', component: SpellingComponent },
  { path: 'definition', component: DefinitionComponent },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the type as submit in Angular Single Page applications. The reason might be

```
<button [disabled]="!authForm.form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn orange darken-1 waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Log In
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

Try using

```
<button [disabled]="!authForm.form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()" class="btn orange darken-1 waves-effect waves-light" type="button">Log In
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 needs an order in paths to show the correct routing, I think the solution is related with the order of paths. For example, you can try this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/auth', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
 { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: 'spelling', component: SpellingComponent },
 { path: 'definition', component: DefinitionComponent },
 { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard' }
];
```

and

```
goToDashboard() {
 this.router.navigate(['dashboard/']);
}
```

Comment: I attempted these changes and it didn't change the query string issue that I'm having after the auth page.